# Why does this not cause a comma splice?

Tags: comma-splices

This sentence appeared on an SAT writing section

> Healthy arctic marine mammals have a thick layer of fat beneath the skin, whereas tropical marine mammals have very few fat reserves in their bodies”

Why is this not considered a comma splice as they are both independent clauses connected by a comma without the use of a FANBOYS.

Comment: You do realize that "FANBOYS" is a myth, right?

Comment: As soon as you use a subordinating conjunction, you have a dependent clause (not two independent clauses).

Comment: To emphasise tchrist's vital comment: **please search for {the myth that is} FANBOYS** in-house (ie here on ELU). But note that articles debunking the usual FANBOYS treatment are at degree level, and may cut across lower-level (in various senses) teaching.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 1):

Whereas is a conjunction. Two independent clauses may be joined with a comma and a conjunction.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whereas?q=Whereas

Comment: But is it not a subordinate conjunction? I thought the only conjunctions that could join two independent clauses were for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so.

Comment: Yes, it is. That's why the _whereas_ clause can be fronted, like any adverbial:  _Whereas tropical marine mammals have very few fat reserves in their bodies, healthy arctic marine mammals have a thick layer of fat beneath the skin._

Comment: Generally subordinating conjunctions that express contrast (whereas, although, etc.) are separated from the preceding clause by a comma, perhaps because the clauses being linked are both independent clauses that contribute to the meaning of contrast equally but can otherwise stand alone. This is an exception case to the general "don't use commas with subordinating conjunctions" rule.

Comment: If it helps you, *whereas* kinda substitutes for *but*.

Comment: There is no "don't use commas with subordinating conjunctions" rule. Some you do, some you don't. [Here's a partial list of both kinds](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/subordinatingconjunctions.pdf).

Comment: @John Lawler Lots of schools teach it, so yes there is. You're entitled to your opinion that it should not be taught that way, but that doesn't change the fact that it is taught that way.

Comment: What I mean is that  English has no such rule. What schools teach just affects their students, and it's rarely correct, and certainly not consistent. Any rule you learned in school is suspect. And it's not my opinion. Note the commas in the subordinate conjunctions in Class II.

Comment: English or any language has no rules at all. Not sure where you're going with this. Lots of people believe (because they have been taught) that there is such a rule, and it seems to me that that "rule" is the driving force behind this question. Say what you want about the legitimacy of rules and schools; it's not relevant.

Comment: Children often believe what they're taught in schools. If they're taught the truth, they're ahead of the game; if not, they can always ask here.